# Customer can win only one quarterly Prize per year provided he has not won 3 monthly prizes

Tags: ambiguity

What does this sentence mean? I am confused.

> Customer can win only one Quarterly Prize per year provided he has not won 3 monthly prizes.

Does it mean that:

1. Customer can only win 1 quarterly prize per year if he has not won 3 monthly prizes?
   OR
2. Customer can only win 1 quarterly prize per year if he has won 3 monthly prizes?

or does it mean something else?

Comment: It's ambiguous. You might need to ask the author what they meant.

Comment: How do you reach conclusion 2? I can't make it mean that. The *not* is important and (2) leaves it out. Please [edit] your question to explain the reasoning why the options might be correct.

Comment: That's what I am trying to ask. I am not native English speaker so I am asking if someone can interpret the question as to what it is asking exactly.

Comment: OK. If it is ambiguous as @JackO'Flaherty says, then perhaps someone can argue for option 2. I can't do that, but I can argue for option 1.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Perhaps it means that female customers are under no such restrictions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Provided [that]" means "as long as" or "if the following applies": it introduces a *proviso*

> A clause in a legal or formal document, making some condition, stipulation, exception, or limitation; a clause upon the observance of which the operation or validity of the instrument depends; *gen.* a condition or qualification; a stipulation or provision. — OED

So the customer can win one quarterly prize per year (and no more than one), but there is a condition that "he has not won three monthly prizes".

Once a customer reaches three monthly prizes, that condition means he's ineligible for a quarterly prize.

It's your option (1).

There are certainly better ways of putting it, particularly since it appears that it's possible to win two monthly prizes and then a quarterly prize, and then perhaps at least one more monthly prize. The sentence wraps up a number of conditions which it would probably be better to separate:

> Winning three monthly prizes makes the Customer ineligible to win a quarterly prize.
> An eligible Customer can win up to one quarterly prize per year.

Answer (score 0):

- 'Customer can win only one Quarterly Prize per year provided he has not won 3 monthly prizes.'

can be re-ordered

- 'Provided he has not won 3 monthly prizes, customer can win only one Quarterly Prize per year.'

Using the 'assuming that' synonym gives:

- 'Assuming that he has not won 3 monthly prizes, customer can win only one Quarterly Prize per year.'

In my opinion this defaults to (and can certainly have the sense)

- 'Provided he has not won 3 monthly prize, customer can win only one Quarterly Prize per year. If he *has* won 3 monthly prizes, he can win *more* than one Quarterly Prize'

But as Jack O'Flaherty says in a comment, the sentence is ambiguous (and violates a Gricean maxim).